# Converting a pandas series with dictionaries inside into dataframes, then append to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe wherein one of its columns has dictionaries inside of it (1 cell = 1 dictionary).

I would like for the key,value pair dictionaries to be two separate columns, and then append them to my original dataframe.

Here's the sample of my dataframe:

[image: Sample Dataframe]

Example is that I want **LUSH ASIA LIMITED** to be in one column and then **1000** to be in another column. I understand that the values of my other columns will repeat when my dictionaries "explode".

I'm not sure if my logic is right, but the idea is to make each dictionary into a new dataframe, then just join them into the original dataframe. I'm not sure though how to do it.

Any advice? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is correct. Maybe this solution can help you. I am directly creating columns with dictionaries. If the columns were actually strings, you may need [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to turn your columns to actual dictionaries.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], columns=['a', 'b'])

# create the dictionary columns - note one dictionary has 1 item only
df['c'] = [{'c': 5, 'e':7}, {'d': 6,}]

# pd.Series is a function that will directly split lists into different columns
# but to use it we must turn the dictionary into a list
# turn the items into a list by unpacking with [*x.items()]
# then flatten that list: for each sublist, take out the elements
df_new = df['c'].apply(lambda x: [l for s in [*x.items()] for l in s]).apply(pd.Series)

# you can then join the dataframes and drop the column with dictionaries if you want
final_df = df.join(df_new).drop('c', axis=1)
```

Input:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   2   {'c': 5, 'e': 7}
1   3   4   {'d': 6}
```

Output: Here the [0, 1, 2, 3] columns came from the step where we applied `pd.Series`. Note how the NaN were also introduced

```
    a   b   0   1   2   3
0   1   2   c   5   e   7.0
1   3   4   d   6   NaN NaN
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. It somehow answered the question; however, I have many key-value pairs inside my dictionary. In your example, what if the dictionary is something like this: `df['c'] = [{'c': 5, 'e':7}, {'d': 6, 'f': 8}]`

How can I split them? Thanks. :)

Comment: @OsheanLeeGaronita I edited my answer with a better answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this. Hmm. It somehow answered my question. However, my desired output though is that the keys should be in just one column and that the values should be in another column; and this will result for the other columns to repeat.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt